# How to revert radio button select on click of cancel?

Tags: jquery

I have two radio buttons. In default it will be male. If i select female and click cancel it should revert to the one before i submitted that is male.

Fiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/0qbgjbog/

I have tried using if condition of trying checking value of the radio button. But its not working.
Please help me out.

**HTML**

```
<form id="myForm">
<input type="radio" name="myRadio" value="Male" checked/> MALE <br />
<input type="radio" name="myRadio" value="Female" /> FEMALE <br />
</form>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply use [`reset`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/button.reset.html) button

```
<form id="myForm">
    <button type="reset">CANCEL</button>
</form>
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/d99e8dws/)

---

```
<form id="myForm">
    //Elements
</form>

<button type="reset" form="myForm">CANCEL</button>
```

[DEMO 2](https://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/0xt2npf9/)

Answer (score 2):

I believe Satpal's answer is the best answer, since you don't need any extra coding for it.

It however resets all form elements. You might only want to reset the radio buttons (with name `myOption`). Then you could use this script:

```
$('button').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('[name=myRadio]').prop('checked', false );
});
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/0qbgjbog/1/)